# Smarty : $smarty.session.someid displayed as $smarty.get.someid

Tags: php, smarty

I have different problem here. In the source I wrote `{$smarty.session.someid}`.

I previously stored `$_SESSION['someid'] = 3`, so it need to show `3` but instead of showing `3` it shows `{$smarty.get.someid}`. I dont know what to do. please help

Comment: looks like smarty is not even processing the template, so you just see the tags as written. Can you give us some context (in the tpl file, how are you calling smarty, etc.)?

Comment: It would help if you show us where you set this var in your php file.